# Hiding fetch request keys

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, reactjs

I am using the new OMDB api, and want to keep the fetch requests (that include the key) out of visibility on client-side.

Here is an example of the problem whenever a user opens up dev tools:[image: feelsbad].

I do all my calls in React like so:

```
  import OmdbKey from './OmdbKey';
  populate(keystrokes) {
    let query = "http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=";
    fetch(query + keystrokes + '&apikey=' + OmdbKey )
      .then((response) => {
        response.json().then((json) => {
          this.setState({ results: json.Search });
        });
      });
  }
```

Is there some way to do this so I can hide the key in the GET request? How else should I approach this if not?

Thanks

Comment: To hide it completely, you'll have to move it server-side, creating a proxy between the client's `fetch()` and OMDB, adding the key in the process. Otherwise, you can obfuscate it so it's less easily recognized (but still possible for anyone determined).

Comment: thanks! Any advice on how to obfuscate without breaking the request?

Comment: Without changing the request, whatever you do, no matter how much obfuscation, network log will show the same. The easiest way could be probably some cloud-function-as-a-service, like [google](http://console.cloud.google.com) , calling it via ajax